# typescript/javascript promise into rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I have some code like below:

```
async someFunction(){ 
    ... 
    await apiRequest()
    ...
  }

apiRequest(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
      this.httpClient.getAuth('/api')}.subscribe({
        next: res => {
            ...
            resolve(true)
        },
        error: error => { resolve(false) }
      })
    )
  }
```

This code is a little bit ugly. Is there any other way to synchronize call of function without using a promise ? Maybe with usage of rxjs? I just need to know that api call finished.

Comment: if rxjs version < 7 use `.toPromise`

Comment: if rxjs v7, use `lastValueFrom` - https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Promises are not the Angular way, Angular is built upon RxJs so it is best to stick to RxJs. apiRequest should return the observable rather than convert it to a promise.

```
apiRequest() {
  return this.httpClient.getAuth('/api').pipe(
    // optional, only if you want service level error handling
    catchError(err => { yourDealWithErrrorFunction(err); })
  );
}
```

then you subscribe where you use it.

```
someFunction() {
  apiRequest().subscribe({
    next: res => { doStuffWithRes(res); },
    error: err => { handleError(err); }
  });
}
```

or we use the async pipe to manage subscriptions in components

```
apiData$ = this.service.apiRequest(); // optionally use a catchError if you want
```

and in the template

```
<ng-template *ngIf="apiData$ | async as apiData">
  apiData is: {{ apiData | json }}
</ng-template>
```

This is the most common Angular pattern. Using promises and async/awaits are not recommended. Learn RxJs, it will make you a better Angular dev. Converting an observable to a promise strips it of it's RxJs superpowers. RxJs operators allow you to construct streams out of observables like combining and mapping streams. This is the way, you wont look back at promises once it clicks even though it is a bit overwhelming at first.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. One of the simplest I think is to use `toPromise` from `RxJS`. But this function is still *deprecated* since version 7. The new function is `lastValueFrom`. Works like this:

```
async someFunction(){ 
    ... 
  try {
    await data = lastValueFrom(apiRequest())
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
    ...
}

apiRequest(){
    return this.httpClient.getAuth('/api');
  }
```

What you can now do is wait for the "someFunction()" like:

```
async loadAllFunction() {
  await someFunction();
  // All loaded... do what you want.
}
```

Comment: This won't work on a subscription right? https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work

Comment: Yes. Sorry. The subscribe will be replaced with the "old" toPromise, so now with lastValueFrom. I will change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- `async` / `await` uses promises (one future value)
- rxjs uses observables where you subscribe to multiple values

  - rxjs also uses `.pipe()` / `.switchMap()` to manage multiple future values

I guess what you are looking for is these two methods, which gives you a promise from an observable.

```
import { firstValueFrom, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: ```async someFunction(){ 
console.log("Before")
    const x = await lastValueFrom(this.someRequest())
    console.log("After")
  }

  apiRequest(){
    return this.httpClient.get('/api').pipe(
      tap(x=>{
        console.log(x)
      }),
      catchError(err=>{
        return of(err)
      })
    )
  }```

I managed to do this. Is this the good way to use tap operator ?

Comment: In this case, you don't need a pipe :). It's only in more complicated scenarios where you have two observables and one depends on another. I'm sure you will encounter that soon enough.

Comment: I think i got the point of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

rxJS has a `from` operator for this - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from